# How can i get data from multiple table in django

Tags: django

how can i get data from this below django html template

```
               <form action="{% url 'purchase_order_item' p_order.id %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-group">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <table id="example-datatable" class="table table-vcenter table-condensed table-bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>#</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Brand Name</th>
                        <th>Product Type</th>
                        <th>Category</th>
                        <th>SubCategory</th>
                        <th>Quantity</th>
                        <th>Unit Price</th>
                        <th>Action</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody>
                   {%  for p in product %}

                    <tr>
                        <td>{{p.id}}</td>
                        <td>
                            {{p.name}}

                        </td>
                        <td>{{p.brand}}</td>
                        <td>{{p.ptype}}</td>
                        <td>{{p.catname}}</td>
                        <td>{{p.supplier}}</td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" id="quantity" name="quantity" value="1" class="form-control">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" id="unitprice" name="unitprice" value="1" class="form-control">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">Add</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    {% endfor %}

                </tbody>
            </table>
           </form>
```

views.py

```
def purchase_order_item(request,id):

now = datetime.datetime.now()
year = now.year
month = now.month
day = now.day
if (len(str(day))) == 1:
    day = '0' + str(day)
if (len(str(month))) == 1:
    month = '0' + str(month)
date = str(year) + '-' + str(month) + '-' + str(day)

randstrn = ""
for i in range(5):
    randstrn = randstrn + random.choice(string.digits)

# catid = Cat.objects.get(name=name).pk
# news = News.objects.filter(ocatid=catid)  # showing post based on master category

supplier = Supplier.objects.all()
p_order = Purchase_order.objects.get(pk=id)
product = Parts.objects.all()



# this is the form for getting data from html
if request.method == 'POST':
    quantity = request.POST.get('quantity')
    unit_price = request.POST.get('unitprice') # itemid = pk type


    nameid = request.POST.get('quantity')



    ref_num = Purchase_order.objects.get(pk=id).order_id

    order_id = Purchase_order.objects.get(pk=id).order_id # get Purchase Order Id for Relational Referance

    




    sv = Purchase_order_item(
        ref_number=ref_num,
                             product_name='sample_name',
                             # product_brand='product_brand',
                             # product_type = 'product_type',
                             # product_cat = 'product_cat',
                             # product_sub_cat = 'k',
                             quantity=quantity,
                             unit_price = unit_price,
                             total_price = '12',
        order_id=order_id

    )
    sv.save()
    # return redirect('purchase_order_item_list')

return render(request,'back/purchase/assign_purchas_item.html',
              {'p_order':p_order,'supplier':supplier,
               'product':product}
              )
```

This is my Models.py

```
class Purchase_order_item(models.Model):


# order_id            = models.IntegerField(default=0) # this is a purchase order id for referance purpose and relation both
ref_number          = models.IntegerField(default=0)
product_name        = models.CharField(max_length=50) # generate an unique Rendome number for farther relation for invoice item
product_brand       = models.CharField(max_length=50)
product_type        = models.CharField(max_length=50) # genuine or after market
product_cat         = models.CharField(max_length=50) # product name
product_sub_cat     = models.CharField(max_length=50) # product name
quantity            = models.IntegerField(default=0)
unit_price          = models.FloatField(default=250)
total_price         = models.FloatField()
order_id            = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

This is my Html screenshot

[image]

Now my question is that ..

how can i get all the listed data after click add button as like Name , brand name , product type , category , subcat , quantity , unit price , etc save to purchase_order_item table .

thanks in advance

Comment: On clicking on add button, you want to save product details in some table or you want to open page with all details?

Comment: my dear i went to save product detail with this input field after clicking add button . but i can do it to get input field data . but not get others data like product name , category , brand etc .